# How to use Fuzzy c means for grey scale image processing in Python?

Tags: fuzzy-c-means

I have 512 * 512 grey scale image.I want to use fcm. But I can not get the fuzzy clusered array after using the code below.As given image is S * N then the fuzzy clustered matrix must be S * N.S means number of features,N means number of dataset.But I got onlt 2 *  1 matrix. Can anyone help me?

```
import skfuzzy as fuzz
image=np.array(image)
original_image=image
original_image=original_image.reshape(-1)
cntr, u, u0, d, jm, p, fpc =fuzz.cluster.cmeans(original_image,2,2,0.005,100)
```

```
print(original_image)
[[0]
 [0]
 [0]
 ...
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]]
```

```
print(u)
[[0.54561414]
 [0.45438586]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the fuzzy c means logo on skfuzzy like this

```
import cv2
import skfuzzy as fuzz
original_image=cv2.imread("covid_5.png")
original_image=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cntr, u, u0, d, jm, p, fpc =fuzz.cluster.cmeans(original_image,2,2,0.005,100)
```